# Pass onmount json to variable

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, svelte

I am fetching json using the Svelte onMount. I have an issue with getting the return json outside the onMount statement.

This is how i fetch my JSON using onMount:

```
let testData = [];
    onMount(async () =>{
        const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/tableinfo.json');
        testData = await resp.json();    
        console.log(testData);    //Returns me array of objects
    });

Console.log(testData) // return me []
```

How do I pass the array of objects and store in testData so that I can call testData with the array in another file?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the line `console.log(testData)` will be executed at component instantiation, which is *before* the `onMount` runs, the expected value is `[]`. Once the component is mounted and `onMount` ran, *testData* will have the correct value. You can try this easily be adding the following line:

```js
$: console.log(testData)
```

This statement will run everytime *testData* will change, you will see two lines in your console, the first one with the initial value of an empty array, the second with your json fetch result.

```
[]
[...]
```

Comment: Okay, I managed to see the json fetch result. Thank you!! But I would like it to be stored in testData so that when I export testData to another svelte file.

Comment: since this looks like a component, you would declare it as being exported: `export let testData = []` but if this is not a component on it's own you don't need all the svelte stuff, you can simply make a `.js` file instead